# Encoutering IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed. when trying to send mailmessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, email, smtp

I have a web application on Asp.Net core with .Net 7 and I need to send emails from it

here are both segments of code where I need to send an e-mail

```
public bool SendMail(string name, string email, string subject, string body)
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            message.From = new MailAddress("sender@example.com");
            message.To.Add("recipient@example.com");
            message.Subject = "Contact from customer: "+name;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Body = "<p>" + "Name: " + name + "</p>" + "<p>" + "Email: " + email + "</p>" + "<p>" + "subject: " + subject + "</p>" + "<p>" + "message: " + body + "</p>";
            smtpClient.Port = 465;
            smtpClient.Host = "mydomain.com";
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx@example.com", "password");
            smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtpClient.Send(message);
            return true;
        }
```

and

```
public bool SendMail(string car, string name, string email, string phone, string service_type, string pickup_date, string pickup_hour, string pickup_minute, string pickup_AM_PM, string pickup_location, string pickup_destination)
        {
            
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                message.From = new MailAddress("sender@example.com");
                message.To.Add("recipient@example.com");
                message.Subject = "Request to book: " + car + " from: " + name;
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Body = "<p>" + "Send Date: " + DateTime.Now + "</p>" + "<p>" + "Name: " + name + "</p>" + "<p>" + "Email: " + email + "</p>" + "<p>" + "phone: " + phone + "</p>" + "<p>" + "Servie required: " + service_type + "</p>" + "<p>" + "Pickup date: " + pickup_date + "</p>" + "<p>" + "Pickup time: " + pickup_hour + ":" + pickup_minute + " " + pickup_AM_PM + "</p>" + "<p>" + "Pickup location: " + pickup_location + "</p>" + "<p>" + "Destination: " + pickup_destination + "</p>";
                smtpClient.Port = 465;
                smtpClient.Host = "mydomain.com";
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx@example.com", "password");
                smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtpClient.Send(message);
                return true;
```

here is what I have

- all the server info and credentials are correct
- the code doesn't work on neither my machine nor the production environment
- it also doesn't work on any email provider (when I was first building it worked perfectly fine with outlook, now it also doesn't)
- when I try to send a test email through an outside test tool (https://www.gmass.co/smtp-test) it works fine with the same settings and credentials

I scoured almost every question on this issue and none of the solutions worked (a lot of answers said to use the port 587, however, the host specifies to use 465 and when I try to use 587 it doesn't work even on the testing site

Edit: My application is hosted on interserver with plesk in case that makes a difference

edit 2: I have solved the issue, turns out it was a cosmic coincidence where the production environment and my machine had two separate problems, for the machine, it was the firewall blocking my attempts, and as for the host it was a simple problem with the credentials.

Comment: 465 is a legacy port. Weird they would tell you to use it explicitly. Anyway, this seems like a TLS issue. Are you looking at an example to try to get this to work? If so, which one?

Comment: at this point my code is just an amalgam of code snippets from various solutions on stackoverflow to try and make it work

the original code was taken from an example, and it functioned perfectly, which is why I'm so perplexed

I didn't change anything about the code except for the smtp config and credentioals and it stopped working

and even when I revert those it doesn't work as well

Comment: According to the error message, it looks like there is some issue happened when doing the tls handshake. This actually is a network issue.  I suggest you should check the client and SMTP support tls version and chipper or some other tls related settings to make sure the handshake could work well.